# Correct way to pull a relationship from another model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

We have a Payments table that links to Sales and Sales links to Clients.  What is the correct way to link to the Clients relationship from the Payments table?

Payments.sale_id -> Sales.id
Sales.client_id -> Client.id

I tried:

```
class Payment extends Model {
    public function sale() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\\App\\Models\\Sale', 'sale_id');
    }

    public function client() {
        return $this->sale->client();
    }
}
```

Which works fine when the sale_id is filled.  However, if the sale_id is NULL, this breaks (obviously because $this->sale is null in that case).

I would like a Laravel solution that still allows access through the `$client` property/attribute.

Comment: Wait, you want to be able to retrieve a `Client` even when there is no `Sale`?

Comment: I just don't want it to cause a fatal error if `Payment::$client` is accessed.  The attribute requires `client()` to return a belongsTo object regardless.

Comment: You can use `Has Many Through` relationship ==> [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: @Maraboc, looks like I need something like a `belongsToThrough` method as `hasManyThrough` doesn't support this direction.  So it looks like there may not be support for this action.

Comment: `client()` may also return `null`, so wouldn't `return (null === $this->sale ? null : $this->sale->client());` suffice? See also https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6161

Comment: @bishop If `client()` returns null, it causes an Eloquent exception when you try to access `$client`.  Saw that issue when searching.  Doesn't look like it will be implemented any time soon.

Comment: Ah, right. Based on how the [Eloquent code is written](https://github.com/illuminate/database/tree/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L2690), overriding the mutator is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution to avoid the fatal error is to use the get attribute mutator instead of `client()`:

```
public function getClientAttribute() {
    if ($this->sale) {
        return $this->sale->client;
    }
    return null;
}
```

We'll see if a better solution comes up.